# What "brightness factor of 20" might mean?

Tags: image, image-processing, pixel, pixel-shader

I'm trying to reproduce a behavior of closed source software. Description of processing contains the following wording, which isnt clear for me:

> ... and a post-process brightness factor of 20.

For me, the term "factor" means "coefficient" or "multiplier", while typical brightness adjustment transform (per intensity sample) uses **addition**, so it is a "summand" or "bias":

```
new_value = old_value + brightness
```

In the other hand, scalar operand used as factor in the linear contrast adjustment transform (per intensity sample again, most basic formula):

```
new_value = old_value × contrast
```

My question outlined in the title: **Which transform this "post-process brightness factor of 20" might really mean?**

---

More context update: the image to be post-processed with that "brightness factor of 20" is being produced by difference operation between two similar images (formula: `C = |A - B|`) so it is naturally very dark.

Comment: My advice: ask the software provider what it means.

Comment: If you can use the software, create an image with  a grayscale gradient, for example, the first row with a value of 0, second row 1, and so on. Apply the operation in your image and see what is the output.

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is curious about resolution, I'm going to post what I did to figure out:

I analyzed a dynamic range of numerous output images and found out what *black point* is always at `0`. This gave me an evidence against bias (addition, as in brightness transform formula). Next, I passed several images thru both my half-baked implementation (w/o that brightness post-processing) and closed source implementation in question (with post-processing). Histograms of processed images looked stretched toward white but otherwise not very informative, so I did dumb and brute arithmetic `result = processed / unprocessed` and got average value of `20`. Average because I apparently have imprecisions in my implementation, but thats a wholly different story.